SPI driver compatibility issue with Linux v6.1
I have a Raspberry Pi CM3+ running with a custom SPI driver working perfectly fine. When I type the command uname -r I get 5.15.92-v7+.
Since a few weeks, I'm trying to adapt my code to a CM4S. On this new device I'm running under 6.1.0-rpi8-rpi-v8. I managed to modify most of my code but I still have an issue with my SPI driver. I recompiled it on my new architecture and I found out that the function spi_busnum_to_master() has been removed.
Here is a snippet of my code:
int init_spi(int int_irq_gpio) {
    struct spi_master *master;
    master = spi_busnum_to_master(SPI0);
    if (master == NULL) {
        printk_ln("Fail to create master spi, SPI bus: %d", SPI0);
        return -1;
    }

    spi_dev = spi_new_device(master, &spi_device_info);
    if (spi_dev == NULL) {
        printk_ln("Fail to create spi device");
        return -1;
    }

    xfer = (struct spi_transfer*)kmalloc(2 * sizeof(struct spi_transfer), GFP_KERNEL);
    xfer_can_send = (struct spi_transfer*)kmalloc(2 * sizeof(struct spi_transfer), GFP_KERNEL);
    xfer_can_dump = (struct spi_transfer*)kmalloc(3 * sizeof(struct spi_transfer), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (init_gpio(int_irq_gpio) < 0) return -1;
    if ((request_threaded_irq(gpio_to_irq(int_irq_gpio), irq_context_INT_handler, irq_thread_INT_handler, IRQF_SHARED | IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING, DRIVER_NAME, DRIVER_NAME)) < 0) {
        printk_ln("Problem while enabling INT irq");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(init_spi);

Doing my research I haven't found any simple way to replace the function spi_busnum_to_master(). When I did this first version, I simply followed a tutorial and I don't really know how to adapt my code.
I just found this topic explaining more in detail my issue. It didn't solved my problem and I would prefer not to change my whole architecture. I would like to adapt my current code if there is any way to do it.

Simplest is to use the device tree overlay.  Otherwise you need to make a struct board_info and call spi_register_board_info which does the bus_num match that you want. See  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.84/source/drivers/spi/spi.c#L855
